# hash for particular array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash

I have a very particular problem that I want to solve efficiently.

A geometry is defined by V volumes, numbered from 0 to V-1.
Each volume is bounded by different surfaces, numbered from 0 to N-1).

```
                            Volume | Surfaces
                            --------------------
Geometry A (V=2, N=7):      0      | [0 3 5 6 2] 
                            1      | [5 4 2 1]
                            2      | [4 0 1 3 6]
```

Note that a **surface will only appear once in a volume**.
Also, **a surface is at most in 2 volumes** of a geometry.

### Here is the problem:

I have two different descriptions of the same underlying geometry and I want to find which volume in Geometry A correspond to which volume in Geometry B. In other words, I have the same N surfaces, but the V volumes are defined differently.

Here is a Geometry B that could correspond to Geometry A above:

```
                             Volume | Surfaces
                            --------------------
Geometry B (V=2, N=7):      0      | [1 5 4 2]
                            1      | [3 6 5 0 2] 
                            2      | [0 1 3 6 4]
```

Given Geometry A and B, I want to be able to bind each volume of Geometry A to its corresponding volume in Geometry B, the most efficiently as possible.

```
A   0  1  2
B   1  0  2
```

### Draft of solution:

Sort each array of surfaces in ascending or descending order, than sort each volume following the lexicographic order of their surfaces. The problem is easily and robustly solved this way.

### Better solution:

Compute a quick, unique hash for each array, than sort volumes following this hash. The hash should not depend on the order of surfaces in the array.

#### Why do I think a hash can be a good solution ?

Take hash(Volume) = min([Surfaces])

This hash already has at most 1 collision, because a surface can only appear in 2 volumes !

Now, if I take hash(Volume) = min([Surfaces]) + max([Sufaces])*N, I still have at most 1 collision, but the probability becomes very small when there is a lot of volumes and surfaces.

Comment: The "better solution" seems workable. Is there something you need help with?

Comment: You're going to have trouble coming up with a "unique" hash. Any hashing scheme has a chance of collision. You can reduce the probability of collision, though. If the number of surfaces is small (less than 32,768), you could encode min and max in the low and high parts of a 32-bit number, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty good hash function, that should almost never have collisions:

```
V: [S_0 S_1 S_2 S_3...S_N-1]

u64 hash(V) = 0;
for i in {0..N-1} :
    hash(V) = hash(V) ^ (1<<(S_i & 63))
end
```

This gives a unique 64 bit number, and all numbers are possible (unlike Omg's solution, where most numbers are impossible to get given that there is no repetition in the list of surface)

In the extreme case where there is a collision (which I will see after sorting), I will compare the arrays lexicographically in a stupid manner.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, your solution is a good approximation for what you want. However, if you seek a perfect hash function, you can use the following method:

> suppose p_i is the i-th prime number such that p_0 = 2, p_1 = 3, p_2 = 5, p_3 = 7, p_4 = 11, p_5 = 13, p_6 = 17, p_7 = 19 .... We can define a hash function on x_0, x_1, ..., x_k from an array such that h(x_0, ..., x_k) = p_{x_0} p_{x_1} ... p_{x_k}. Also, for the repeated numbers, we can apply the number of repetition as a power of the p_{x_i}. It means, for example, if x_i is repeated 3 times, the power of p_{x_i} in `h` would be p_{x_i}^3. if number of repetition of x_i is a_i we will have h(x_0, ..., x_k) = p_{x_0}^{a_0} p_{x_1}^{a_1} ... p_{x_k}^{a_k}.

Hence, for geometry A we have:

```
                    Volume |      Surfaces     | Hash
                    ----------------------------------
  geometry A           0   | [0, 3, 5, 6, 2]   | 2 * 7 * 13 * 17 * 5 = 15470 
                       1   | [5, 4, 2, 1]      | 13 * 11 * 5 * 3 = 2145
                       2   | [4, 0, 1, 3, 6]   | 11 * 2 * 3 * 7 * 17 = 7854
```

And the similar way for geometry B. As this function returns a unique value for each array (without concern with the order) you can arrange the surfaces using the correspondence hash value. If the value of `N` is not big, you can use the precomputed list of prime values.

Comment: Your hash is pretty beautifull mathematically, has it indeed gives a unique hash. However, with only 10 primes, its already 32 bit, and it wouldn't need 20 primes to overflow a 64 bit... With the overflow, I guess there would be a lot of collision.

Actually, the problem of this hash function is that it doesn't take advantage of the fact that numbers do not repeat. I will describe a better hash function in a following answer.

Comment: @yakoudbz the second problem is too easy. The answer is updated. The only concern is about the type which is not the concern in the question. Anyhow, it is not the concern in all languages such as python : )

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have mentioned that the underlying concern is about efficiency. I do not want to use big numbers (which are always slow, even in python: https://jasonstitt.com/c-extension-n-choose-k). Upvoted anyway